# calling function twice or more and getting TypeError 'int' is not callable

Tags: python-2.7, function, typeerror

I need some help with one my functions, The first time you call it, it works perfectly, however on subsequent runs through an if/else statement it gives out TypeError 'int' is not callable. in order to see this, when given the option use Hunt, then on the second run use Hunt again. I am using Python 2.7, code is: -

```
from sys import exit
import random

equipment = ['Bolter', 'Bolt Pistol', 'Combat Knife']

print "Your ship has crash landed on an unknown planetoid, what do you do? 
Explore, Overwatch, Hunt or Nothing"

def enemy_attack():
enemy_attack = random.randrange(0, 7)
if enemy_attack <= 5:
    print "Enemy Misses"
    print "Your Turn"
    you_attack()
elif enemy_attack == 6:
    print "Enemy kills you"
else:
    print "Enemy ran away"

def you_attack():
you_attack = random.randrange(0, 7)
if you_attack <= 2:
    print "You missed"
    print "Thier Turn"
    enemy_attack()
else:
    print "You killed the enemy"
    print "What do you do? Explore, Overwatch, Hunt, or Nothing"

    do = raw_input("> ")

    if "Explore" in do:
        print "You find a sealed container"
        print "Your Equipment is", equipment
        print "Do you want to open the container? Yes or No"
        container = raw_input("> ")
        if "Yes" in container:
            open_container()
        else:
            print "You left it alone"
    elif "Overwatch" in do: 
        print "Orks Attack!!!" 
        enemy_attack()
    elif "Hunt" in do:
        print "You attack the Orks!"
        you_attack()
    else:
        print "The planetoid swallows you whole, and adds your mass to it!!"
        exit(0)

def open_container():
open_container = random.randrange(0,5)
if open_container == 0:
    print "You have found a Plasma Gun!"
    equipment.append('Plasma Gun')
    print "Your equipment is now", equipment
elif open_container == 1:
    print "You have found a Chainsword!"
    equipment.append('Chainsword')
    print "Your equipment is now", equipment
elif open_container == 2:
    print "You have found a Power Sword"
    equipment.append('Power Sword')
    print "Your equipment is now", equipment
else:
    print "There is nothing here for you!!"


do = raw_input("> ")

if "Explore" in do:
print "You find a sealed container"
print "Your Equipment is", equipment
print "Do you want to open the container? Yes or No"
container = raw_input("> ")
    if "Yes" in container:
        open_container()
    else:
        print "You left it alone"  
elif "Overwatch" in do: 
    print "Orks Attack!!!" 
    enemy_attack()
elif "Hunt" in do:
    print "You attack the Orks"
    you_attack()
else:
    print "The planetoid swallows you whole, and adds your mass to it!!"
exit(0)
```

Comment: enemy_attack is function and variable too. WHY? You should use some good variable/function name

Comment: Please fix the indentation to make it easier to read.

Comment: You're calling `you_attack()` from inside `you_attack` - however - the very first thing you do is set `you_attack` to an integer inside the function, so the name's rebound for the scope and you try and call an integer. Rename your variable... `attack_strength` or just `strength` or something...

Comment: @JonClements, thank you for that, code works perfectly. I recognise my failing and will be sure to correct it.